# HQL Query having conditions on associated object's associated objects

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have following query :

`FROM PatientInfo AS pi WHERE pi.customerApplicationPatient.customerApplication.customerApplicationId = :customerApplicationId  AND pi.customerAppPatient.patient.patientId = :patientId`

PatientInfo, CustomerApplicationPatient are associated and customerApplicationPatientId is the foreign key column.

CustomerApplicationPatient is associated with CustomerApplication , Patient with customerApplicationId, patientId as foreignkey columns.

> Question : Get all the PatientInfo records given customerApplicationId and PatientId. My query is a good query in the sense, not producing too many inner joins or cross-joins ? Is there a better way of doing this ?

I really appreciate any help and hope the question is clear.

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: You should remove the `sql` tag as this contains no SQL.

Comment: @user1290226 Could you please point me to sql code in above HQL query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not rely on implicit joins when you need to reference them in your where clause.

So instead of:

```
FROM PatientInfo AS pi WHERE
pi.customerApplicationPatient.customerApplication.customerApplicationId = :customerApplicationId 
AND pi.customerAppPatient.patient.patientId = :patientId
```

to

```
select pi 
from PatientInfo AS pi
inner join pi.customerApplicationPatient cap
inner join cap.customerApplication ca
inner join cap.patient p
where
    ca.customerApplicationId = :customerApplicationId 
    AND p.patientId = :patientId
```

The explicit joins will be translated to the exact join statements you'd expect. The previous query might not be that clever and might join the same child table twice.

Comment: Thank you and I would try both queries and see the difference.